# Sharepoint Date picker jumps to the top of page in Chrome ...and now in IE!

Tags: form, chrome, datepicker, ie

I have an issue with the Chrome browser, and found the next "solution" in this site:

```
function OnIframeLoadFinish() {
ULSvmd:
    ;
    var picker;    
    if (typeof this.Picker != 'undefined')
        picker = this.Picker;
    if (picker != null && typeof picker.readyState != 'undefined' && picker.readyState != null && picker.readyState == "complete") {
        document.body.scrollLeft = g_scrollLeft;
        document.body.scrollTop = g_scrollTop;
        g_scrollTop = document.getElementById('s4-workspace').scrollTop;
        picker.style.display = "block";
        if (typeof document.frames != 'undefined' && Boolean(document.frames)) {  /* "document.frames" doesn't work on chrome use "window.frames" instead*/
            var frame = document.frames[picker.id];    
            if (frame != null && typeof frame.focus == 'function')
                frame.focus();
        }
        else {
            picker.focus();
        }
    }
    setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById('s4-workspace').scrollTop = g_scrollTop;
    }, 1);
}
```

the thing is that this code works perfectly in Chrome. But once I paste it, now it is making the jump in **Internet Explorer** (and without this code, the jump only happens in Chrome).. **So I'd like to know an answer that works in both browsers!**.

I tried putting an *if* with a code that recognizes the browser so it applies only when you are using Chrome, but it didn't work, it's still making the jump in IE whenever I paste the code above.. I need help 9_9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found the answer.. in case somebody wants to know:
When I put the condition I did it the wrong way in first instance, I was putting the condition OUTSIDE the function **OnIframeLoadFinish()**, but the code works when putting the condition INSIDE the function:

```
function OnIframeLoadFinish() {

    if (!!window.chrome) {
        ULSvmd:
        ;
        var picker;
        if (typeof this.Picker != 'undefined')
            picker = this.Picker;
        if (picker != null && typeof picker.readyState != 'undefined' && picker.readyState != null && picker.readyState == "complete") {
            document.body.scrollLeft = g_scrollLeft;
            document.body.scrollTop = g_scrollTop;
            g_scrollTop = document.getElementById('s4-workspace').scrollTop;
            picker.style.display = "block";
            if (typeof document.frames != 'undefined' && Boolean(document.frames)) {
                var frame = document.frames[picker.id];
                if (frame != null && typeof frame.focus == 'function')
                    frame.focus();
            }
            else {
                picker.focus();
            }
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById('s4-workspace').scrollTop = g_scrollTop;
        }, 1);
    }
}
```

the thing is that the function will always run, independently of any condition, so that's why the "if you're using chrome" condition only works inside the function